# Reduce max in tensorflow for grouping rows?

Tags: python, tensorflow, tensorflow2.0

I have a tensor I want to calculate max in every column grouped by certain rows.

Eg: tensor_eg =

```
[[0.1 0.2 0.4 0.5],
 [0.1 0.8 0.2 0.5],
 [0.1 0.2 0.4 0.5],
 [0.1 0.1 0.6 0.5]]
```

tf.reduce_max(tensor_eg, axis = 0) would give me the max value for each column over all rows. I would like to do it grouped by certain rows, say max for row 0 and 1, and max for row 2 and 3:

Wanted result:

```
[[0.1 0.8 0.4 0.5],
 [0.1 0.2 0.6 0.5]]
```

How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe just try slicing and using `tf.concat`:

```
import tensorflow as tf

x = tf.constant([[0.1, 0.2, 0.4, 0.5],
                 [0.1, 0.8, 0.2, 0.5],
                 [0.1, 0.2, 0.4, 0.5],
                 [0.1, 0.1, 0.6, 0.5]])

tf.concat([tf.reduce_max(x[:2, :], keepdims=True, axis=0), tf.reduce_max(x[2:, :], keepdims=True, axis = 0)], axis=0)
```

```
<tf.Tensor: shape=(2, 4), dtype=float32, numpy=
array([[0.1, 0.8, 0.4, 0.5],
       [0.1, 0.2, 0.6, 0.5]], dtype=float32)>
```

A more generic approach would be to use `tf.math.segment_max`:

```
x = tf.constant([[0.1, 0.2, 0.4, 0.5],
                 [0.1, 0.8, 0.2, 0.5],
                 [0.1, 0.2, 0.4, 0.5],
                 [0.1, 0.1, 0.6, 0.5]])

tf.math.segment_max(x, tf.constant([0, 0, 1, 1]))
```

The segment ids need to be equal to the size of `x`'s first dimension

Comment: Okay, nice! Can this solution be extended to more group? Say I don't know which rows to group, I get that as an input parameter. So in the case above I get group_rows = [0, 0, 1, 1]. But in other cases I get group_rows = [0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3, 3, 4, 4] (assuming x have 13 rows in this case). Can your solution be made more generic?

Comment: [0, 0.. ] would be a group referring to the first and second rows in `x`?

Comment: yes exactly, just a way of specifying which rows to group in x